# Problema generando un link en laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, html5

Tengo un problema manejando archivos, en mi aplicación subo mi archivo normal, pero cuando lo quiero visualizar en mi vista como un enlace `<a>` no funciona, a continuación muestro mi método en el controlador y el resultado que obtengo:

```
->addColumn('anexos', function ($entity) {
                if ($entity->anexos) {
                    $viewLink = route('custom-storage', ['file' => $entity->anexos]);
                    return '<a href="' . $viewLink . '" target="_blank">' . $entity->anexos . '</a>';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            })
```

Cuando mi vista rederiza la locación del archivo, muestra algo como:

`<td>"<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom-storage/1693161592_Ensayo%20final.pdf" target="_blank">1693161592_Ensayo final.pdf</a>"</td>`

En vez de:

`<td><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom-storage/1693161592_Ensayo%20final.pdf">Ensayo final</a></td>`

En la vista final, se me da cuando veo una evidencia que es subida como  link desde mi formulario y es exactamente así:

```
->addColumn('evidencia', function ($entity) {
                if ($entity->evidencia) {
                    return '<a href="' . $entity->evidencia . '" target="_blank">' . $entity->evidencia . '</a>';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            })
```

¿Qué tengo mal? ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Estas usando datatables, cierto? Si es así, prueba como dice en su documentacion https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/raw-columns